# Do I need my code-behind file?

Tags: wpf, code-behind

In my WPF app, all I have in my code-behind is the following:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{    
    public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }    
}
```

Can I completely remove the code-behind file from my project or does it have to stay there? My background is in web app development and I'm kind of relating this to a code-behind file with an empty Page_Load() method, which I would typically remove.

Comment: Did you try removing code behind?  Why don't you comment out that InitializeComponent(); line and see what happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **can** remove it, if you use one of these techniques:

1: Remove the `x:class` declaration from the top of your XAML file, and find a different way to instantiate the object (e.g., you can't use `new MainWindow()`, but you can use `XamlReader.Load` and cast the result to a Window).

or

2: Use this approach:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
  <StackPanel>

    <Button x:Name="mybutton">Hello</Button>

    <x:Code>
      <![CDATA[
      public MainWindow()
      {
        InitializeComponent();

        mybutton.Content = "Goodbye";
      }
      ]]>
    </x:Code>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This moves the InitializeComponent call into your XAML, so you can delete the codebehind file.

Answer (score 2):

No! `InitializeComponent()` actually creates all the controls defined in the XAML file, and hence is very necessary.

See more info here: [What does InitializeComponent() do, and how does it work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can remove it.  Specifically, the InitializeComponent() function needs to be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove it. It initializes your Window (all buttons, labels, etc.).