# kinect basics and C#

Tags: c#, wpf

i have recently started  working on kinect for windows.i am beginner in C# i was hoping if any of you could tell me what does the part before and after colon mean in ---> **"mainwindow:window"**

and i can't figure out what "  intializeComponent()" is doing.  even though when i commented it the codes still works fine  so what is this actually doing  and when i looked for its definition  by pressing F12 it took me to the new file named "mainwindow.g.cs

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="MainWindow.xaml.cs" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.ColorBasics
{
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using Microsoft.Kinect;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Active Kinect sensor
    /// </summary>
    private KinectSensor sensor;

    /// <summary>
    /// Bitmap that will hold color information
    /// </summary>
    private WriteableBitmap colorBitmap;

    /// <summary>
    /// Intermediate storage for the color data received from the camera
    /// </summary>
   private byte[] colorPixels;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute startup tasks
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Look through all sensors and start the first connected one.
        // This requires that a Kinect is connected at the time of app startup.
        // To make your app robust against plug/unplug, 
        // it is recommended to use KinectSensorChooser provided in Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit
        foreach (var potentialSensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
        {
            if (potentialSensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
            {
                this.sensor = potentialSensor;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (null != this.sensor)
        {
            // Turn on the color stream to receive color frames
            this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

            // Allocate space to put the pixels we'll receive
            this.colorPixels = new byte[this.sensor.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength];

            // This is the bitmap we'll display on-screen
            this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameWidth, this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameHeight, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

            // Set the image we display to point to the bitmap where we'll put the image data
            this.Image.Source = this.colorBitmap;

            // Add an event handler to be called whenever there is new color frame data
            this.sensor.ColorFrameReady += this.SensorColorFrameReady;

            // Start the sensor!
            try
            {
                this.sensor.Start();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                this.sensor = null;
            }
        }

        if (null == this.sensor)
        {
            this.statusBarText.Text = Properties.Resources.NoKinectReady;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute shutdown tasks
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void WindowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != this.sensor)
        {
            this.sensor.Stop();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for Kinect sensor's ColorFrameReady event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void SensorColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            if (colorFrame != null)
            {
                // Copy the pixel data from the image to a temporary array
                colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixels);

                // Write the pixel data into our bitmap
                this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(
                    new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
                    this.colorPixels,
                    this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
                    0);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the user clicking on the screenshot button
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void ButtonScreenshotClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null == this.sensor)
        {
            this.statusBarText.Text = Properties.Resources.ConnectDeviceFirst;
            return;
        }

        // create a png bitmap encoder which knows how to save a .png file
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

        // create frame from the writable bitmap and add to encoder
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(this.colorBitmap));

        string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh'-'mm'-'ss", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);

        string myPhotos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

        string path = Path.Combine(myPhotos, "KinectSnapshot-" + time + ".png");

        // write the new file to disk
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                encoder.Save(fs);
            }

            this.statusBarText.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", Properties.Resources.ScreenshotWriteSuccess, path);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            this.statusBarText.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", Properties.Resources.ScreenshotWriteFailed, path);
        }
    }

    private void Image_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does InitializeComponent() do, and how does it work? (WPF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-wpf)

Comment: @Erno the op had another question

Comment: @DanielA.White - It boils down to "What is InitializeComponent?" Anyway, others can vote if they agree or not.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to Kinect, but its C# things that you have questions about.

Where your question is around `MainWindow : Window`, that is your class is called `MainWindow` and the colon signifies [inheritance in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). That is, `MainWindow` is a subclass of (or inherits) `Window`.

As for `InitializeComponent` check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/245881/23528