# Take screenshot of WinForm after it has loaded

Tags: c#, arguments, screenshot

I have a screenshot application where a user can pass command line arguments, and based on those arguments will determine the behaviour of the form.

I am trying to take a screenshot after the form has loaded, however I have the functionality to do this after `InitializeComponent();`. Like so-

```
if (counts > 0)
        {
            generateScreenshotButton_Click(null, null);

            button2_Click(null, null);
        }
```

My problem being these functions are firing **before** the form has loaded. Therefore the screen shot is blank. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Add Loaded event... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx

Comment: Side note...create methods and call them instead of event handlers. `button2_Click` tells nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Load` event in your `Form.cs` file.

There is a difference between `InitializeComponent` and `Form Load`. See [What does InitializeComponent() do, and how does it work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-wpf) It is for WPF but is same in Windows Forms.

Try this code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); //this is the InitializeComponent method. this This method locates a URI to the XAML for the Window/UserControl that is loading, and passes it to the System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent() static method. 
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load); //this create Load Form event
        }

        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) //after your form is completely loaded, your program will run the code from here...
        {
            //your code goes here
        }
```

Hope that I helped you.

Comment: This still fires the button click before the form has fully loaded?

Comment: No, this is the idea. If you put your method inside of `Form1_Load` button click will be fired after form was fully loaded.

Comment: i dont understand this, currently my button click is in the initialise component section, this is also where I gather the values. What do you suggest I put into Form1_Load????

Comment: See the edits. Hope that you understand better. Did you try to put your code in `Form1_Load`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using MainForm [`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event?
And in that event handler do your stuff? :)

Or maybe using [`Shown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) event?