# Moving text in textbox c# using location and left function

Tags: c#, textbox

I've got a problem with my WFA, I need to write a program, which moves user input text in form, and I need to use function like Location and Left, the text should move with random speed. I tried to use Timer to move this, but it doesn't work ... 
I put my code below.

```
namespace Neon2
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Location = new Point(15, 15);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     textBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right & AnchorStyles.Bottom & AnchorStyles.Top & AnchorStyles.Left;
        try
        {
            textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        }catch(InvalidEnumArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error! " + ex.Message, "error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        textBox1.Location = new Point();
   }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){}
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to move text, when it is edit? or every time?

Comment: i want to move text for example to right side, when i just type something in textbox

Comment: you mean, every time you enter text will appear on right side?
then you have to used 
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;

Comment: no, I mean, it will be moving and look like it was animated, and this text should move to rightside

Comment: see this example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390239/text-animation-on-a-windows-form-c-sharp
may this helps.