# Visual Basic: Write to StreamWriter from different Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, streamwriter

I have tried looking for a similar problem but I haven't found any for VB.

I have multiple forms, all of which with their own design and function. Form1 creates a StreamWriter file and will launch the other forms. Form2 and so on need to be able add to the same file, however I cannot access the file from the other forms.

I have tried declaring the file as Public in Form1, and also I have tried using:

Form1:

```
Dim newForm As New Form2(myFile)
newForm.show()
```

Form2:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal myFile As StreamWriter)
    Me.myFile = myFile
End Sub
```

but this will load Form2 without any of the controls I put on it in design mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `InitializeComponent()` method

```
Public Sub New(ByVal myFile As StreamWriter)

InitializeComponent()

Me.myFile = myFile

End Sub
```

For more info read [Very Simple definition of InitializeComponent(); Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297079/very-simple-definition-of-initializecomponent-method)