# Why does my checkedListBox throws NullReferenceException in C#?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, checkedlistbox

I am trying to populate my checkedListBox with a txt file.

Here is my code:

```
public Form1()
{
   StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(allatPath, Encoding.Default);
   while(!sr1.EndOfStream)
   {
       allat = new Allat(sr1.ReadLine(), sr1.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(sr1.ReadLine()), sr1.ReadLine());
       allatok.Add(allat);
       checkedListBox1.Items.Add(allat.Nev);
   }

   InitializeComponent();
}
```

I get the following error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

checkedListBox1 was null.

Comment: How/where did you declare and initialize `checkedListBox1`?

Comment: It seems pretty clear. You are using a control before [calling InitializeComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297079/very-simple-definition-of-initializecomponent-method)