# C# WPF Visibility of a TextBox in window constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a a window class with a hidden textbox.
I am using a constructor with 1 parameter (string).
And if that parameter = "a"  I want to make the textbox visible.

```
  public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1(string x)
    {
        if(x == "a") this.TBOcena.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

but it seems i am doing something wrong because it does not work.
I am getting an exception
`"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'"`

Not sure how to fix it and not even sure what to look for in google : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All references to named controls in XAML must be done after a call to `InitializeComponent()`. Whether that's on the constructor or not is up to you

Comment: Wow that simple...  Thank you very much. It is working fine now.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted (using the tick mark next to the answer) if it was correct to you :-)

Comment: I'll in 6 minutes when it let's me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call directly the InitializeComponent method in that constructor:

```
public Window1(string x)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if(x == "a") this.TBOcena.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

or you could create a default constructor and call it:

```
public Window1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
} 
public Window1(string x):base()
{
    if(x == "a") this.TBOcena.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

The call to InitializeComponent() (which is usually called in the default constructor of at least Window and UserControl) is actually a method call to the partial class of the control (rather than a call up the object hierarchy as I first expected).
You can find more details of this method in this post:[What does InitializeComponent() do, and how does it work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-in-wpf)