# How to reference and use label in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently playing with wpf for the first time and I'm coming into some issues. I cannot figure out how to reference the wpf label element. I changed my label name to "label1" and try referencing it in my c# code, but alas no result just errors such as.

xaml

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Rustomatic.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Rustomatic" 
    Height="350" 
    Width="525" >
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="F5" Command="{Binding Hit}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

c#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;


namespace Rustomatic
{

public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    label1.content = "hi";

}

public class Hit 
{



}   

}
```

Please take it lightly I was an intermediate at C# once but I haven't used it in a couple of years.

Comment: Your c# code is the same as xaml, fix it please

Comment: I have 2 questions, 1. what is your error? and 2. don't you need to initialize the component like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-in-wpf)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You give names to elements in xaml by  using `x:Name`, this will cause them to be publicly named in designer generated cs-file (it is made out of xaml) and you can access them as you did it in past in winforms.

This code doesn't makes any sense:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    label1.content = "hi";
}
```

You can't access `label1` like this. You have to do it in the property getter/setter or method:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        label1.Content = "hi";
    }
}
```

Also, don't remove constructor `InitializeComponent()` call, otherwise your window will not get initialized. This is important (unless you add partial class *in addition* to partial class made for you when you add new window to project):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```