# Cannot access control items after switching windows in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry about the title but I don't really know how to word the problem. Basically, I have a log in screen which comes up when you start the program. After the user logs in successfully, the current window is switched with

```
MainWindow obj = new MainWindow(userNameTextBox.Text);
App.Current.MainWindow = obj;
obj.Show(); //after login Redirect to second window  
this.Close();//after login hide the  Login window
```

I then try to fill a datagrid on the next window but get this error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have tried just setting the text in a label and get the same error. When I have tried setting the text in a label in the login.xml.cs code (so after the this.close line) it works using this line

```
obj.label.Content = "test";
```

Why can I not access the wpf controls in the current window?

Comment: Call `InitializeComponents()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks. I was calling the method that used components before InitializeComponents() in the constructor.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark/rate my answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are calling `InitializeComponents()` for your WPF before your method that is using the componenets.

Helpful Referenece: [What does InitializeComponent() do, and how does it work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-in-wpf)