# In WPF why binded properties are public but the event subscription is private?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF world and just started reading WPF. While reading I found whenever we bind some Element to property in code behind that property always needs to be public and DataContext needs to be set even if that property lies in xaml.cs file. But the method subscribed to the event can be private.

For ex:
In following example SelectedCountryIndex property is public but Country_SelectionChanged method is private.

xaml  file:

```
<ComboBox Name="Countries" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCountryIndex}" SelectionChanged="Country_SelectionChanged"/>
```

xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         DataContext = this;
      }
      public int SelectedCountryIndex{ get; set; } = 0;
      private void Country_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){}
}
```

Now as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344321/what-is-the-connection-between-xaml-and-xaml-cs-files) Mainwindow.xaml.cs's class is partial like MainWindow.xaml's class hence it is straight that we can write 
Countries.SelectionChanged+=Country_SelectionChanged and now Country_SelectionChanged can be private.
But why this does not happen with binding? If we set property as public then only code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a slight misunderstanding. `private void Country_SelectionChanged(...)` is not your event; it is merely the handler for the event. There is still a public event of SelectionChanged.

Take for instance `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It has an event like so:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

The `event` is what you are actually using when you do `PropertyChanged += MyFooHandler`.

`MyFooHandler` can be public, private, internal, etc. It doesn't matter what the accessor is, but the event needs to have the proper visibility to allow for things to wire into it.

Properties for WPF binding need to be public so that the framework itself can easily see it and work its magic. There's much more behind the scenes than just having `{Binding Foo}`. ;)

Comment: Properties have to be public because WPF will not violate data encapsulation. If a member is private then the intend is clear: hide it from the public. If you want a member to be accessible from outside declare it public. WPF simply doesn't break this compiler rules to encourage robust code. When defining a binding source the developer has a clear intent to expose data.

Comment: Event handlers on the other side do not reflect such an intent. Event handlers are usually never public because they are part of the class' internal logic.. Most important the method is invoked by the instance itself. The `Delegate` uses the `Delegate.Target` (the owner of the event handler) to invoke the `Delegate.Method`. It doesn't invoke the method directly (which would cause an exception when the method is declared as private.

Answer (score 0):

Binding is done using reflection to figure out public properties on the DataContext type. This is because your DataContext can be a different class than the view, usually a View Model class in MVVM scenarios.

Your event handler on the other hand is always in the same class, and the access modifier `private` is good enough to access this.