# Inherit from "Application" in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently building a set of application in WPF, they will use Prism as framework.

They will have a lot in common, and the only thing that will changes between 2 of my app is what will be loaded in the Prism region.

So I wanted to put some things in common.

One thing that I didn't succeed is to make one common "Application" implementation with all the common part:

The goal was to have:

> Application <-- BaseApp(abstract) <-- MySpecificAppplication(code behind only)

The goal is to have every resources declarations in BaseApplication, the `OnStartup` implementation in common, and only the specific part(in my case, which Bootstrapper I want to run) in the end class.

Here are some code:

```
public abstract partial class BaseApp : Application //This class has also some XAML for resources loading, but pretty basic.
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        BaseBootstrapper clientBootstrapper = GetBootstrapper();
        //Some initialization stuff
        clientBootstrapper.Run();//This will cause Prism to load the correct first View(shell)
    }
    protected abstract BaseBootstrapper GetBootstrapper();
}
```

And the specific implementation

```
public  class MySpecificApp : BaseApp
{
    protected override BaseBootstrapper GetBootstrapper(){
        return //something ;
    }
}
```

But I build, I get an error:

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry
>   point

Is this supported?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new WPF Application in Visual Studio using the default template, you get an `App` class that do inherit from `System.Windows.Application`.

The compiler adds a `Main()` method to this one for you, and in this method an instance of the `App` class is created and the [InitializeComponent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-in-wpf) method is called to parse the XAML before the [Run()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx) method is called to start the application.

You can add define the `Main()` method yourself if you want to:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
public static void Main()
{
    App app = new App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

But obviously you cannot create an instance of an abstract class. So if `BaseApp` contains XAML, it shouldn't be defined as an abstract class.

The alternative would be move the XAML and the `Main()` method to your `MySpecificApp` class and create an instance of this one in the `Main()` method.

Comment: I see, but then I loose the "I don't want to import my set of styles 10 times", any workaround?

Comment: Put the styles in a resource dictionary that you merge into the app or window?