# Can't perform button click in constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to invoke a button click event automatically when the WPF form loads. So I'm calling it in the constructor right before initializeComponent();. But it always gives me the following error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

the code is:

```
logoutBTN.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

how can I fix this?

**EDIT, SOLUTION**
This does the job! Thanks.

```
Loaded += (s, e) => logoutBTN.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

Comment: add to the Loaded += (put here);

Comment: does it should look like this? 
Loaded += (logoutBTN.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent)));
Because it won't compile

Comment: Loaded += (s,e) => logoutBTN.RaiseEvent(....

Comment: @kenny that works great! Thank you. Can you help me with one more thing? How can I achieve the same thing, but with invoking just a method, not a button click? But the same way, coz I can't load it with just method();

Comment: I got it, thank you @kenny!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:
You should place your code **after** the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Explanation:
The `InitializeComponent()` method is where all the controls within your WPF class are instantiated. If you make any references to the controls before it, you would most likely get a null reference exception. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-in-wpf) article for more information.

**Edit based on comment:**

If this is the case you should only trigger this event after the page is fully loaded, you could register to the window's loaded event:

```
this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            logoutBTN.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
        };
```

Comment: This fixed my null reference exception! BUT, it looks like I can't initialize the button click because I get some interference with mysql connections. The button click get's an image from the database. But if I let the form initialize, and then clicking the button manually it loads perfectly. Maybe I should delay the automatic btn click?

Answer (score 1):

After `InitialiseComponent();`
Add:

```
this.Loaded+=new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonClickEvent);
```