# How to setup a WPF project in MVC format?

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller

I've been looking into better dividing up a WPF project. So far, this example has made the most sense to me (MVC style):

[image]
Source: https://www.codemag.com/Article/1201061/CODE-Framework-Writing-MVVM-MVC-WPF-Applications

So I'm trying to figiure out best how to divvy up my project in this fasion. It seems that by default in WPF projects for each form a .xaml file is created, then a .cs file (controller?) is nested within it.

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is the .xaml file always going to be the 'view'?
2. Is the .xaml.cs file always going to be the 'controller'?
3. Since it doesn't appear a 'model' is created by default in the WPF structure, should my steps for setting up project structure be like this:

   a.) Separate the .xaml from it's .xaml.cs file.

   b.) Put the separated .xaml file in a Views folder

   c.) Put the separated .xaml.cs file in a Controllers folder

   d.) Create a Models folder

   e.) Create new class in Models folder that will be used by the .xaml.cs controller file we put in the controllers folder.

Does this seem accurate? I am trying to structure my code best for an interview, so I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: 1) yes 2) no.  Actually the .cs is completely optional and can be deleted 3a) optional 3b) if you want 3d) if you want 3e) possibly.   Well, if you are going for an interview I suspect you would fail with a MVC approach.  Generally WPF is MVVM not MVC

Comment: @MickyD is right, MVC is better on ASP.NET. On WPF, you should use MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the .xaml file always going to be the 'view'?'

Yes.

> Is the .xaml.cs file always going to be the 'controller'?

No. This is the code-behind file of the view. By default, it calls the compiler generated `InitializeComponent(`) method to load the XAML markup that is defined in the `.xaml` file. Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-in-wpf) for more information. The markup in `.xaml` and the code in `.xaml.cs` are partial classes of the same view. They belong together.

> a.) Separate the .xaml from it's .xaml.cs file.

No. This makes no sense for the reason mentioned above.

> b.) Put the separated .xaml file in a Views folder

You can put the views in a separate folder, but this includes the `.xaml.cs` files as well.

> c.) Put the separated .xaml.cs file in a Controllers folder

No. There is no concept of "controllers" here.

> d.) Create a Models folder

Sure.

> e.) Create new class in Models folder that will be used by the .xaml.cs file

This is an option, but you would generally create a view model class that references the model and exposes properties that the view binds to. Please refer to [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/) for some basic introduction to the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) design pattern which is *the* recommended design pattern to use when developing XAML based UI applications. You will find a lot more information and examples if you Google or Bing for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reviewing this framework which is beginning to look promising - check it out:
https://www.codemag.com/article/1201061/CODE-Framework-Writing-MVVM-MVC-WPF-Applications

The article and ideas are well presented (yes in English) and actually make sense.  While it may not result in an immediate answer to your problem, I've been looking for framework templates that actually mimic/implement the MVC pattern correctly and I think I found it - finally!